# SQLite table returning Null Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I am working on an Android Activity that reads Date of Birth entered by the user and instantiates an object with the value. The date is then stored in an SQLite table. The problem is that I get a NULL date value when I query the table later for the Date.

The date is being received correctly by the constructor of the object. However, it returns NULL when queried for it later.

It will be great if you could point out the error.

**Method that reads the Date, instantiates the object and stores in SQLite. The value is being read from EditText dob**

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameinput);
            final EditText dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobinput);
            final EditText mobile_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mnuminput);
            final EditText alt_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altnuminput);
            final EditText email_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailinput);
            final EditText home_adr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeadrinput);
            final EditText off_adr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.offadrinput);
            final EditText notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notesinput);
            final TextView flag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insertflaglabel);

            String name_converted = name.getText().toString();
            String mobile_no_converted = mobile_no.getText().toString();
            String alt_no_converted = alt_no.getText().toString();
            String email_id_converted = email_id.getText().toString();
            String home_adr_converted = home_adr.getText().toString();
            String off_adr_converted = off_adr.getText().toString();
            String notes_converted = notes.getText().toString();

            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            Date dob_converted = new Date(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

            try {
                 dob_converted = df.parse(dob.getText().toString());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("add_client", "Date read is " +dob_converted);
            client client_new = new client(name_converted, dob_converted, mobile_no_converted, alt_no_converted, home_adr_converted, off_adr_converted, email_id_converted, notes_converted);

            Context context = getBaseContext();
            database_handler insert_client = new database_handler(context);
            Log.d("add_client", "Date instantiated is " +client_new.getDOB());
            insert_client.addClient(client_new);
            flag.setText("Client Details Saved!");
        }

    });
}
```

**Method that queries SQLite for Date of Birth using .getDOB()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_clientdetails);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Integer tab_id = 0;

    if (extras != null) {
        tab_id = (int) extras.getInt("client_id");
    }

    TextView namev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namevalue);
    TextView mobnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mnumvalue);
    TextView date_ob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dobvalue);
    TextView altnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altnumvalue);
    TextView off_addr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offadrvalue);
    TextView home_addr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeadrvalue);
    TextView email_addr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailvalue);
    TextView notes_client = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notesvalue);

    Context c_displayclient = getBaseContext();
    database_handler dhandle = new database_handler(c_displayclient);

    String TAG = "display_clientdetails";

    Log.d(TAG, "Value of ID is " +tab_id);
    final client c_details = dhandle.getClient(tab_id);
    namev.setText(c_details.getName());
    mobnum.setText(c_details.getMobile_number());
    altnum.setText(c_details.getAlt_num());


    DateFormat datef = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

    Log.d("display_clientdetails", "Date of Birth is " +c_details.getDOB());


    String text_date = datef.format(c_details.getDOB());
    date_ob.setText(text_date);
```

**Instantiation Code**

```
    // constructor
    public client(String name,Date dob,String mobile_number,String alternate_number,String office_address, String home_address,String email_id,String notes)
    {

        this.name = name;
        this.dob=dob;
        Log.d("client", "dob received in client constructor is " +this.dob);
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
        this.alternate_number=alternate_number;
        this.office_address=office_address;
        this.home_address=home_address;
        this.email_id=email_id;
        this.notes=notes;
    }
```

**Method that returns the Date of Birth**

```
    // getting Date of Birth
    public Date getDOB(){
        Log.d("client", "Date returned is " +this.dob);
        return this.dob;

    }
```

**Method that Adds a new entry to the Database Table**

```
  public void addClient(client client_instance) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, client_instance.getName()); // Client Name
    values.put(KEY_MO_NO, client_instance.getMobile_number()); // Client Phone
    values.put(KEY_DOB, client_instance.getDOB().toString());
    values.put(KEY_ALT_NO,  client_instance.getAlt_num());
    values.put(KEY_OFF_ADR, client_instance.getOff_adr());
    values.put(KEY_HOM_ADR, client_instance.getHome_adr());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, client_instance.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_NOTES, client_instance.getNotes());

    db.insert(TABLE_CLIENTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }
```

**Method for Getting Data from the Database**

```
 // Getting single contact
  client getClient(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    client client_instance = new client();
    String TAG ="database_handler";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CLIENTS, new String[] {
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_MO_NO, KEY_DOB, KEY_ALT_NO, KEY_OFF_ADR, KEY_HOM_ADR, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NOTES}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);


    if(cursor != null) Log.d(TAG, "cursor is not null");
   // if(cursor.moveToFirst()) Log.d(TAG, "move to first is true");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        client_instance.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        client_instance.setMobileNumber(cursor.getString(1));

        //Convert Datefield from String to Date so that the setDOB method can accept it as argument

        DateFormat dateform = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
        Date d_of_b = new Date(DateFormat.FULL);

        try {
            d_of_b = dateform.parse(cursor.getString(2));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Set Date of Birth
        client_instance.setDOB(d_of_b);

        client_instance.setAlt_num(cursor.getString(3));
        client_instance.setOff_adr(cursor.getString(4));
        client_instance.setHome_adr(cursor.getString(5));
        client_instance.setEmail(cursor.getString(6));
        client_instance.setNotes(cursor.getString(7));
        Log.d(TAG, "Email is " +cursor.getString(3));
        cursor.close();
    }

    return client_instance;

}
```

**Method for Setting the Date of Birth into a new Client Instance**

```
   public void setDOB(Date dob){
    this.dob = dob;
   }
```

Comment: How are you storing data in database?

Comment: did you check the database, whether is it getting stored properly?

Comment: What is data type of Date you used in SQLite? TEXT?

Comment: @LocHa The data type of Date is String in SQLite. I am doing that because I was not able to figure out how to give a starting value to a Date variable in private static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";

Comment: @Kesh1234 I checked the database. It is storing the correct value there. I am storing the String version of the date in the database by converting the Date to String using .toString()

Comment: @Apurva I have edited the question to append the Code for storing the data in database.

Comment: What is the code to read client from DB?

Comment: And how are you getting those data? also add that method from your dbHelper

Comment: @LocHa I have added the code for pulling the data from the database. I indentified an error in the code. I have started getting the following error now: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 1970"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your issue is you have to use the same Date format when you format & parse date.
2. You should use Specific date format such as "MM/dd/yyyy"
3. Your solution is

   - When you format Date ( When inserting client into SQLite)

     ```
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
     String dobAsString = format.format ( dob_Date_object);
     // Store dobAsString in SQLite
     ```
   - When you parse Date (When reading client from SQLite)

     ```
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
     String dobAsString = // ... Read from SQLite

     Date dob = format.parse(dobAsString);
     ```
4. You should not use String for store DATE data. You should use Long datatype (Convert Date to timestamp - long data type). See below reason:

   - If you use String:  "06/12/2014"  Greater than "03/12/2015":  WRONG!!!
   - If you use Long:    Long_timestamp("06/12/2014") Less than Long_timestamp("03/12/2015"): Correct